# IF formula to display a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have an Excel workbook with four sheets where:

Sheet 1 will be used by a user
Sheets 2-4 will be hidden for raw data.

and I have used data validation to create a drop down for uses to be able to select searchable criteria, how do I display a range of cells from the raw data based upon their selection?

Eg. If user selects 1, it would show all data from cells A1-C35, Sheet 3. If they selected 2, it would show all data from cells A14-C46, Sheet 3. Etc etc.

Comment: While not impossible, it would be somewhat tricky to do this while maintaining the aesthetics of the sheet. You'd need a formula in each cell that could potentially be populated with a value (meaning large areas of empty values when the returned range is a smaller one). Alternatively, you could combine the use of some helper columns on your raw data sheets with filtered pivot tables on your user interface sheet - this would offer a more dynamic result-set, but requires that your users know a little about how pivot tables work.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with @JoeMalpass, this question requires to show at least three different sets of data in a common area, if these sets of data are not similar *(same fields and data types)* showing them with the correct format is an issue, even using pivot tables will not be possible without user intervention to point to the correct fields. *Needless to say using VBA will be simpler and effective.*

Now coming back to the formula solution *(and being aware of the format issues)*, this solution includes:

1. Adding Defined Names at worksheet level *(scope)* for each of the set
   of data.

In the worksheet where the data will be displayed:

2. Adding a list of the Defined Names (fig. 1)
3. Adding a DataValidation and some formulas with relevant information about the size of the data sets (fig. 2)
4. Range to display data sets (fig. 3)

The use of Defined names allows handling several sets of data in the same worksheet

**Data Sets**

For this test I used 4 data sets in different worksheets. 
Add Defined Names for each data set at worksheet level, for simplicity I used always the common name *“DATA”* unless there are several data sets in the same worksheet *(i.e. “Sheet2” contains two data sets*)*

**List of Defined Names**

Used for the DataValidation and to display size of the ranges
[image]
fig. 1

Use the following formulas for the fields

**Name** – builds the Defined Name used in DataValidation and formula to display data

```
 =CONCATENATE("'",$C3,"'!",$D3)
```

**Worksheet & Range**: Enter the worksheet and Defined Names assigned to each data set

**Rows** – Shows number of rows of Defined Name

```
 =IFERROR(ROWS(INDIRECT($B3)),"!Err")
```

**Columns** – Shows number of columns of Defined Name

```
 =IFERROR(COLUMNS(INDIRECT($B3)),"!Err")
```

**Address** – of Defined Name (Optional)

```
=CONCATENATE(
ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT($B3)),COLUMN(INDIRECT($B3))),":",
ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(INDIRECT($B3),$E3,$F3)),COLUMN(INDEX(INDIRECT($B3),$E3,$F3))))
```

**Displaying the data**

[image]
fig. 2

Use the following formulas for the fields

**Select Data**: Add DataValidation in cell `J2` pointing to `B3:B6`

**Rows** – Number of rows for selected data set

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(INDIRECT($J$2)),"!Err")
```

**Columns** – Number of columns for selected data set

```
=IFERROR(COLUMNS(INDIRECT($J$2)),"!Err")
```

**OffsetRow** – Used in the formula to display data

```
 =-1+ROW($I$11)
```

**OffsetColumn**: – Used in the formula to display data

```
 =-1+COLUMN($I$11)
```

*OffsetRow & OffsetColumn: should point to first cell of range used to display the data i.e. `I11`*

Range used to display selected data *(can be entered also as Array Formula)*
This range should has at least the maximum number of rows and columns as per the List of Defined Names *(i.e 35 rows & 4 columns)*

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($J$2),-$J$5+ROW(),-$J$6+COLUMN()),"")
```

[image]
fig. 3

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, nicely done. Note, the use of `INDIRECT` is great for small data sets, it can make things a bit sluggish on larger sheets because it is a volatile function and requires recalculation any time anything changes in the workbook (even changes made to cells that have no impact on the those using or referenced by the indirect function). No clue what the impact will be here as the asker has not alluded to the size of their workbook, hopefully it will be a non issue.

Comment: Thanks @JeoMalpass for the reminder about the volatility of 'INDIRECT', honestly it’s something I often forget as most of the time I use manual calculation. As you mentioned there is no indication of the size of the data, however if this is to be used on very large data definitively the solution should involve VBA. Also there is no mention the use of the data displayed, but it seems that it is for a kind of report or information only, in which case formatting would be an issue.